# Qt QGraphicsScene how to separate select and unSelect signals?

Tags: qt, selectionchanged, qgraphicsscene

I am creating an app in qt, and i have come to a problem.

I have a qgraphics scene.
I create the scene and I have put some actions to take place when the user clicks
on a scene item.

I can detect the `selectionChanged()` signals, but:

1. The signal is emitted twice (once for the clicked item and once for the previously selected item (deselection), so the required actions take place twice for both items).
2. When an item is clicked, it remains selected and i can't click it again...
   (i tried setting `item->setSelected(false)` but it gets in an infinite loop of selection/deselection...).

Anyone has any idea how to fix that?

What I am trying to achieve, is to have no action performed on deselection,
and to be able to re-click a clicked item and re-perform the action.

Answer (score 1):

Define a slot `yourSlot()` and connect it to the signal `selectionChanged()`. In this slot you check if the item responsible for the signal emission is selected or not.

```
void yourSlot() {
   QGraphicsItem  *item = qobject_cast<QGraphicsItem  *>(sender());

   if (item) {
      if ( item->isSelected() ) { //this item is selected
         doSomethin();

         //*deselect* the item so that it can be selected again
         item->setSelected(false);
      } 
      else { //the signal was fired because the item was deselected
        //ignore()
      }
   }
}
```

I can't try it right now because I don't have Qt installed in this computer by I think it should work.

Comment: i tried that, but it goes into infinite loop... it seems that the `item->setSelected(false)` fires up a new signal
and the same item seems to be selected... i don't know... something weird is happening in my code... :( thanks anyway for the answer...